# Apache Nifi MergeContent - wrong output size

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I am having issues using the MergeContent processor. Specifically, it looks like it does not obey to the configuration, and groups flow file inconsistently.

That's my current flow:

- csv files are splitted line by line into rows
- a **merge.id** attribute with a **UUID** as value is added to each row
- rows are splitted into records which are processed individually

Now I need to get back records together according to the **merge.id** value. That's how my MergeContent processor is configured:

[image]

What I get is that the first couple rows are correctly merged back together after processing, then I start getting less then the specified value of 10. Is this an incorrect behavior? I am missing something?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: When you specify a merge.id, is this being done explicitly on the row content or as an attribute?

Comment: I specify it as a FlowFile attribuite. I tried to slow down the rate of the incoming FlowFiles, and I am not experiencing these issues anymore. Could it be related to the number of bins being too few with respect to the incoming rate? I would have expected a warning instead of this behavior.

Comment: yes, if that is the case, I would suspect the number of unique values for your correlation id is exceeding the maximum number of bins, at which point, the processor will start flushing bins out to make room for new records being received.  This is currently logged but at a debug level.  If you adjust the processor's bulletin level to debug, we could confirm the suspected behavior.

Comment: I had it on 'INFO', that's why I did not notice anything. Is there a suggested limit for the number of bins? If I schedule n tasks for that processor, do I get n times that max number of bins? Anyway, I switched to 'DEBUG' but no debug entry is displayed live on the processor. I tried getting over the logs with grep but still no debug entry is present. I am however able to reproduce the error lowering the number of bins and tasks. Do you think it may be something else?

Comment: Would you be able to create an issue (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI) and share a template of your flow so we can dig in a bit more to see what is going on?

Comment: Sure. I've never done it but I will definitely try. Thanks for your help.